# How far is this view correct on strengthening and weakening of the topologies of the domain and the codomain?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, open-map

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a map between *infinite* topological spaces. I want to know how correct is this view on how refining (strengthening) and coarsening (weakening) the topologies on both the domain and the codomain affects a mapping being continuous and open mapping.

**Question:** *Is there in general such diagram, (or a similar one,) that holds true whenever one starts from the trivial topologies and refines them (taking anyway) towards the discrete topologies ?*

[image]

---

Starting from the trivial (chaotic) topologies, there are too many paths toward the discrete topologies, not only one, but is there a diagram of that sort above that holds no matter what, i.e. will change "homeomorphically" under changing the path of refinment.

Feel free to suggest corrections and diagrams.

Comment: I think first of all we need to have in mind that the topologies on a given topological space do not form an ordered set with respect to inclusion. So, a diagram like that with just 2 axis would be very very vague. You can weaken and sthrengthen the topologies in more that one way in principle

Comment: Yes, starting from the trivial (chaotic) topology, there are too many *paths* toward the discrete topology, not only one, but is there a diagram of that sort above that holds no matter what, i.e. will change "homeomorphically" under changing the path of refinment ?

Answer (score 0):

***Note**: this answer is not entirely applicable anymore, as the question has changed.*

Your diagram implies that if you have any continuous non-open map between $X$ and $Y$, it is always sufficient to weaken the topology of $X$ to make the map continuous and open. This is simply not true in general.

---

**Example**: Take $X=[0,+\infty)$, $Y=\mathbb R$, and $f(x)=x$ being the inclusion map. Consider on $Y$ the Euclidean topology and on $X$ the [topology induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology) by the map $f$, i.e., the weakest topology that makes $f$ continuous (this induced topology on $X$ coincides in turn with the Euclidean topology, as the topology induced by the inclusion map is just the subspace topology). The map is then continuous but not open, as the image of $X$ is $[0,+\infty)\subset Y$. If you then weaken the topology of $X$ to try to make $f$ open, you necessarily end up making it discontinuous.

If you instead strengthen the topology of $X$, you necessarily have a non-open map, as “you have even more sets to be tested for openness”. You can play around with this example and similar ones to see how and where the diagram fails. I think an interesting way is to fix one of the two topologies and let the other one vary starting from the topology induced by the map $f$, which should correspond to the treshold you drew between the “continuous” and “non-continuous” regions.

Comment: Just a small comment. I have answered some time ago one of your questions about the Banach-Steinhaus theorem. I would really appreciate that you have a look at my second answer to know if that is what you were thinking :)

Comment: Yes, I remeber. After this semester I hope, because currently I really have no time. I'm still beginner in functional analysis and it will take me some time to understand the answers on my questions

Comment: I see, no problem!

Comment: If one starts from the trivial topologies on both, the dashed lines do not need to meet at this pair of topologies at all, ie.e they are neither continuous nor open, e.g. the map in your answer, but for maps between singletons it has to include them since in that case any map is continuous and open, if we exclude finite sets, then *perhaps* your example was one on the boundary below the region of (open and continuous), do you understand me ?

Comment: Not quite, sorry. What I mean is that my example lies on the edge between “continuous” and “non-continuous” (essentially because $f$ is continuous, but if I weaken the topology of $X$ or even strengthen the topology of $Y$ the map is not continuous anymore), but at the same time is not open, while your diagram says it should be open

Comment: In your example you have a continuous but not open mapping, that you can make open by "strengthening the topology of the codomain" by adding to $Y$ the open set $[0, \infty)$ (and all other open sets that this forces). This seems to work perfectly well with OP's diagram.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I hope you excuse me this week, I'll check it later

Comment: @MeesdeVries , yes you can make it continuous and open strengthening the topology of $Y$, but not weakening the topology of $X$. On the diagram, instead, it seems to me that if you start at a point in the “continuous non-open” region and descend vertically, you always cross the region “continuous and open”.

Comment: Maybe it was not that clear from the first paragraph. I deleted the part about changing the topology of $Y$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili I should say that this is a very rough diagram so it is certainly not precise, but the question is whether there is such, i.e. similar, diagram for, at least for infinite sets

Comment: Your question now sounds much better.